# AWS SQS Java SDK: Endpoint Override With A Path

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I am using the AWS SDK version 2.14.26.

I want to be able to point it to my simulator for AWS SQS, which allows for me to do fancy things such as return errors, delay responses, ect. I do have ElasticMQ, but I also want to do the fancy things, for which I have a webapp which simulates many things, one of which would be SQS.

My webapp is hosted at http://localhost:8088/simulators/v1/aws/sqs. I would hope I could then expect the sdk to make any API requests starting from that path https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-making-api-requests.html

For example,

```
https://sqs.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/   
?Action=CreateQueue
&DefaultVisibilityTimeout=40
&QueueName=MyQueue
&Version=2012-11-05
&AUTHPARAMS
```

Would become

```
http://localhost:8088/simulators/v1/aws/sqs   
?Action=CreateQueue
&DefaultVisibilityTimeout=40
&QueueName=MyQueue
&Version=2012-11-05
&AUTHPARAMS
```

But when I create the client and try to get a queue:

```
SqsClient client = SqsClient.builder()
                .region(Region.of("SIMULATOR"))
                .credentialsProvider((()->AwsBasicCredentials.create("ignored", "bySim")))
                .endpointOverride(new URI("http://localhost:8088/simulators/v1/aws/sqs"))
                .build();
client.getQueueUrl(GetQueueUrlRequest.builder()
      .queueName("test123")
      .build());
```

I get

`software.amazon.awssdk.services.sqs.model.SqsException: null (Service: Sqs, Status Code: 404, Request ID: null, Extended Request ID: null)`

Looking at wireshark, it seems to just be pointing at / rather than the endpoint I wanted, which caused it to get a 404

```
1287    2020-10-12 16:07:10.982955272   127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   HTTP    801 POST / HTTP/1.1  (application/x-www-form-urlencoded)
[Full request URI: http://localhost:8088/]
```

Is there a way to get the aws sdk to start from the path of /simulators/v1/aws/sqs? Because I would like my simulator app to be able to simulate may APIs, and not have to use the root path.

Comment: X-Posted to aws fourms as well: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=329509

Comment: I was able to do a workaround by creating a reverse proxy. I used https://github.com/tomkraljevic/jetty-embed-reverse-proxy-example/blob/master/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/ProxyServer.java

I had to make a few changes for my version of jetty:

Comment: 1. Use ServerConnector rather than socket connector
ServerConnector http = new ServerConnector(server);
        http.setPort(8089);
        http.setHost("localhost");

Comment: 2. Change "ProxyTo" to "proxyTo"

Comment: 3. Obviously change the proxyTo url to `http://localhost:8088/simulators/v1/aws/sqs`

Comment: I would Still enjoy a clean solution though